# Printing to a USB Label Printer with CUPS

Tags: 14.04, printing, cups-lpd

I am trying to print a simple text file to a USB label printer connected to my Ubuntu 14.04 system.

The text file is simple :

```
echo "Test Passed" > file.txt
```

I found my printer as follows :

```
lpinfo -v

...
direct usb://Brother/QL-570?serial-=J2Z376442
...
```

I created a printer as follows :

```
lpadmin -p Label -E -v usb://Brother/QL-570?serial-=J2Z376442
```

Now when I try to print :

```
lp -d Label file.txt
```

I get :

```
request id is Label-8 (1 file(s))
```

Promising / expected reply, but nothing comes out on the label printer (yes it is plugged in / online).

Anyone encounter a situation like this / have any thoughts?

Comment: Did you install the printer driver? My laser's came from the Brother website.

Comment: Your sample print text should be followed by LF/CR and possibly FF.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for over two days over that issue.
For me the answer was pretty simple. The i386 version of cups need to be installed for the printer to do anything.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL Pellet Norman

# Unrelated to CUPS. Just need to set the timezone to avoid the interfactive mode
ENV TZ=Europe/Zurich
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Cups installation
RUN mkdir -p /var/spool/lpd

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y cups cups-bsd &&\
    apt-get install -y libcups2:i386

# Some other stuff for me
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils &&\
    apt-get install -y nano

# Copy the drivers
COPY pt9800pcncupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386.deb /root/pt9800pcncupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386.deb
COPY pt9800pcnlpr-1.0.1-1.i386.deb /root/pt9800pcnlpr-1.0.1-1.i386.deb
COPY ptp950cupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb /root/ptp950cupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb

# Install the drivers
RUN dpkg -i  /root/pt9800pcnlpr-1.0.1-1.i386.deb
RUN dpkg -i  /root/pt9800pcncupswrapper-1.0.1-1.i386.deb

# Copy the access control, etc, that was defined from the WSL implementation
COPY cupsd.conf /etc/cups/

# Add root to the lp group. But ok that's not really necessary
RUN usermod -a -G lp root

# Here's I'm copying the printer ppd files that I will use later to overwrite the config given by Brother
COPY printers /home/docker/printers

# A test document to print
COPY document.pdf /home/docker/document.pdf

# The setup script
COPY setup.sh /home/docker/setup.sh

#ADD cupsd.conf /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
ENTRYPOINT /home/docker/setup.sh && /bin/bash
```

And the startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
service cups restart

lpadmin -p PT-9800PCN-2N25 -h 127.0.0.1:631 -E -v socket://IP_ADDRESS -P /usr/share/cups/model/Brother/brother_pt9800pcn_printer_en.ppd
cp -R /home/docker/printers/* /etc/cups/ppd
lpr -H localhost:631 -P PT-9800PCN-2N25  -o media=MY_CUSTOM_SIZE /home/docker/document.pdf
```

And as soon as the docker runs, document.pdf gets printed !

I mostly stumbled onto the libcups2:i386 missing binaries.